# completion error: "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"?

Tags: swift, swiftui, rest

I am getting a "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" error and I don't know why! Please help me out so the code will work again plz!

whole code:

```swift
class GarbageService{
    let garbageBaseURL : URL?
    init(){
        garbageBaseURL = URL(string : "http://localhost:5000/garbages/findstreets?")
    }
    func getGarbageSchedule(street : String,completion: @escaping (GarbageModel?) -> Void)
    {
        if let garbageURL = URL(string:"\(street)",relativeTo: garbageBaseURL!){
            let clientApi = networkManager(url : garbageURL)
            clientApi.DownloadJSONFromURL{
                (jsonDictionary) in
                print(jsonDictionary as? [String : Any])
                //TODO Parse JSON Object into weather object
                if let garbageDataDictionary = jsonDictionary?["STREETS"] as? [String:Any]{
                    let garbageData = GarbageModel(garbageDictionary: garbageDataDictionary)
                    completion(garbageData)
                }
                else{
                    completion(nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
let garbageService = GarbageService()

garbageService.getGarbageSchedule(street: "HATHAWAY DR",completion: (GarbageModel?) -> Void){
    {(garbageData) in
        print("STREETS: "+String(format:"%s",garbageData?.street as! CVarArg))
    }
}
```

snippet giving error:

```swift
let garbageService = GarbageService()

garbageService.getGarbageSchedule(street: "HATHAWAY DR",completion: (GarbageModel?) -> Void){
    {(garbageData) in
        print("STREETS: "+String(format:"%s",garbageData?.street as! CVarArg))
    }
}
```

it really bugging me out

Comment: the garbageService.getGarbageSchedule() line is giving me error

Comment: Please show GarbageModal

Comment: Also instead of String(format:) you should be able to use string interpolation: "Streets: \(garbageData?.street)" you may be more likely to see the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `street` is `String` both `String(format` and the type cast are not needed and will crash if an error occurs.

And there are too many braces, remove the inner pair of braces

```
garbageService.getGarbageSchedule(street: "HATHAWAY DR") { garbageData in
     print("STREETS: " + garbageData?.street ?? "An error occurred")
}
```

The format specifier `%s` is wrong anyway. The specifier for a Swift `String` is `%@`

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't fix the issue with my type of ambiguous error

Comment: Remove the parameter label and the type annotation (`,completion: (GarbageModel?) -> Void` in the function call

Comment: ok now there is a problem with {(garbageData) in print()} part. Error is "Unable to infer type of closing parameter garbageData in the current context"

Comment: code for so far is as follows:
 
garbageService.getGarbageSchedule(street: "HATHAWAY DR"){_ in
    {(garbageData) in
        print("STREETS: \(garbageData?.street as! CVarArg ?? "error occurred")")
    }
}

Comment: is this what you wanted?

Comment: No, the inner braces are wrong, again please see my edit. And stop that pointless type cast to `CVarArg`